# Gradle only compiles one file?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, compilation

So I'm having troubles compiling multiple Gradle files. I'm new to Gradle so that's probably the first reason why it doesn't work as I intend.

Currently my Gradle file looks like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.3.61'
}

group 'com.github.polyrocketmatt.sierra'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url = "https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots"
    }
    maven {
        url = "https://raw.github.com/PolyRocketMatt/PolyCommand/mvn-repo/"
    }
    maven {
        url = "https://repo.minebench.de/"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compileOnly 'org.spigotmc:spigot-api:1.16.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'org.jetbrains:annotations:16.0.1'
    compile 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.4.2'
    compile 'com.github.polyrocketmatt.polycommand:PolyCommand:1.1'
    compile 'de.themoep:inventorygui:1.4.3-SNAPSHOT'
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

And my source tree looks like this:

[image: Source]

It only compiles the Sierra class, and I want to compile with it all the other classes too of course. This is what I see when I decompile the JAR file Gradle builds for me:

[image]

How do I make sure all the other classes are compiled with it?

Comment: JAR packaging is not a compilation. What do you see in `build/classes/kotlin` directory when you run `gradle classes`?

Comment: In that folder all classes are present. But how can I all package them into one jar?